# SS2012 Export Wizard Access is denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, import

When a user exports to a flat file she gets an access denied error.  The wizard allows her to preview the data so she has access on the db side.  From Windows she can create a new file in the target destination so she seems to have network permissions.  She is logged into her computer with a network username and into SS2012 with a SS login.  Everyone else can run the export wizard to this location successfully.  I am stumped!

Comment: Why is she using a local SQL Server login? A SQL Server login cannot authenticate to a network resource without a proxy as far as I know and can remember if you have the folder security ACL settings correctly configured at least. Perhaps there is an elaborate workaround but try having the user use their domain username and grant it the DB permissions and then that may solve the problem. The issue is likely the SQL Server login ID does not MODIFY permission to the folder it's exporting to but if the domain username does, then using that to authenticate to SQL and exporting with it should too.

Comment: Walmart,
All our users logon to their computers with Domain logins and into SS with SS logins.  This is a legacy issue.  Remember,  all the other users can export successfully.

Comment: It's hard to say without being there and looking over your setup. I've never had any luck getting local SQL Server logins to authenticate to network resources without using a proxy and using the RUN AS from a SQL Agent job or `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` or whatever it is using straight T-SQL. I could probably figure this out without a lot of time if I were there since I've spent hours and hours on such issues in the past and know all the gotchas.... I'd see for yourself how it works from a different account from the beginning until the end and then compare with the one it doesn't work for to start.

Comment: Walmart, 
I have run the wizard start to finish successfully on several other computers and accounts.  The wizard actually lets you choose a combination of local and network credentials for both the data source and destination.  Kind of cool how you can use 2 different sets of logins in a single application.

Comment: Does everyone use the same SS login? If not, or does the export work if someone else uses her SS login on their system, and if she uses someone else's SS login on hers?

Answer (score -1):

T.H.  Everyone has a their own logins.  I love your idea to try someone elses SS login from her machine.  Unfortunately the export was successful from her machine with my SS login and also a success from my machine with her SS login.  I say unfortunately because it now works from her machine with her own SS login.  The issue has resolved itself but I don't know why! :-(